# Как добавить поле в шаблон веб формы Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

мне нужно добавить своё поле в веб форму, но при использовании своего шаблона ничего не отображается, а где взять стандартный?Всмысле вёрстку или может как то по другому можно добавить своё поле в форму?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]